# nginx: Location block for all URIs without extension

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, regex

I know how to process URIs that match a certain pattern.

**Example**

The following configuration will add an Cache-Control http-header to all files ending with .css or .js:

```
location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
  add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable" always;
}
```

**Question**

How can I process all URIs without extension?

Something like `www.domain.tld/my-article`.

(I use nginx as an reverse-proxy and I add the extension `.html` in the `.htaccess`.)

Comment: So the final path element does not contain a `.`, for example: `location ~ /[^./]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is:

```
location / {
    # Everything else
}

location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable" always;
}
```

[nginx location directive documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) explains in detail how nginx evaluates different `location` blocks.

Comment: Is in the example above `\.(?:css|js)$` the same as `\.(css|js)$`?

Comment: The `?:` tells regular expression engine not to capture the part to variable. This makes the expression a bit faster.